# Reduce space after title with big paragraph whitespace

Tags: context

How can I remove the space between the section title and the first line of text while keeping the big paragraph space?

I have tried multiple variations with `\setuphead[section][after=...]` (e.g. `{\blank[-1cm]}` and `{\blank[none]}`) but I was not able to remove the space entirely.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]
\starttext
\startsection[title={Section A}]
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
after={\blank[nowhite]},
```

or

```
after=\nowhitespace,
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\setupwhitespace[big]
\setuphead[section][after={\blank[nowhite]}]
\starttext
\startsection[title={Section A}]
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

### Explanation

If you understand TeX primitives, here is what is happening. `\setupwhitespace` sets the `\parskip` while `\blank[...]` is a `\par\vskip`. So, when you use

```
\setupwhitespace[big]
\blank[none]
```

you still see the white space due to `\parskip`. To get rid of the `\parskip`, you can use `\nowhitespace`, which is equivalent to `\blank[nowhite]`.

How can a `\vskip` get rid of a `\parskip`? This is part of an experimental code in ConTeXt, where the vertical space has multiple categories (as explained in [`spac-ver.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/spac-ver.mkiv)):

```
% category:
%
%  0 == discard                             discard
%  1 == only if larger                      largest
%  2 == force even if smaller               force
%  3 == only take penalty component         penalty
%  4 == add to existing skip                add
%  5 == disable (ignore following)          disable
%  6 == kill whitespace                     nowhite
%  7 == discard previous                    back
% 10 == no topskip
%
% penalty: larger wins
% order: larger wins
% category:2,order:5,penalty:10000,skip:value|kw
```

and then ...

```
\definevspacing[\v!always]    [category:0] % hm, internally it's discard
\definevspacing[\v!max]       [category:1]
\definevspacing[\v!force]     [category:2]
\definevspacing[\v!disable]   [category:5]
\definevspacing[\v!nowhite]   [category:6]
\definevspacing[\v!back]      [category:7]
%               together      [category:8]
\definevspacing[\v!overlay]   [category:9]
\definevspacing[\v!enable]    [category:10]

\definevspacing[\v!weak]      [order:0]
\definevspacing[\v!strong]    [order:100]

\definevspacing[\s!default]   [\v!white] % was big for a while
```

The actual implementation is in [`spac-ver.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/base/mkiv/spac-ver.lua) (but I don't understand it well enough to comment).